# There is extra space in my div of the header on the left?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to complete CSS exercises for flexbox from Odin Project. This is the self check:

Self Check

- There is space between all items and the edge of the header (specific px amount doesn't matter here).
- Logo is centered vertically and horizontally.
- list-items are horizontal, and are centered vertically inside the header.
- left-links and right-links are pushed all the way to the left and right, and stay at the edge of the header when the page is resized.
- Your solution does not use floats, inline-block, or absolute positioning.

However, there is extra space in the div of class left-links that doesn't make sense on why it is there in HTML or CSS code as I did not add any there myself.

It should look like this:[image]
But this is what I got: [image]

I've tried so many ways to get left-links pushed to the left to no avail.

```css
.header {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  background: papayawhip;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 9px 4.5px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: white;
  padding: 4px 32px;
}

ul {
  /* this removes the dots on the list items*/
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 9px;
}

a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px;
  /* this removes the line under the links */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.left-links a {
  align-items: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flex Header</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="left-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="right-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ul`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) has the default padding. If you want to get rid of it, you can reset that padding value like below

```
ul {
   padding: 0;
}
```

```css
.header {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  background: papayawhip;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 9px 4.5px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: white;
  padding: 4px 32px;
}

ul {
  /* this removes the dots on the list items*/
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 9px;
  padding: 0; /*Removed the default padding*/
}

a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px;
  /* this removes the line under the links */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.left-links a {
  align-items: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flex Header</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="left-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="right-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule:

```
.left-links > ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

It erases the default left-padding of the `ul` inside the `.left-links` container.

And add `align-items: center;` to the rule for `.header`, which vertically centers the elements in there:

```css
.header {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  background: papayawhip;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 9px 4.5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: white;
  padding: 4px 32px;
}

ul {
  /* this removes the dots on the list items*/
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 9px;
}

a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px;
  /* this removes the line under the links */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.left-links a {
  align-items: left;
}
.left-links > ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flex Header</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="left-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="right-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```